# VBA Datalabel.Top being assigned to a variable incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts, label

I am creating a chart, adding series on it, then I apply a data label to the last point of each series. I then run a routine which prevents overlaps from happening. In some conditions it works when I debug it however it does not work when I let it run normally. I think I have found the source of the error but don't know how to fix it.

First I apply data labels

```
 'add data label to line
Worksheets(OutputSheetName).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(x).Points(NumberOfSamples + 1).ApplyDataLabels
Worksheets(OutputSheetName).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(x).Points(NumberOfSamples + 1).DataLabel.Text = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(PlotRow(x), TransistorNameY).Value & " " & Sheets(SheetName).Cells(PlotRow(x), DeviceTypeY).Value _
& " " & "[" & Sheets(SheetName).Cells(PlotRow(x), ColdCurrentY).Value & " " & "A" & "]"

'increasing data label width
Worksheets(OutputSheetName).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(x).Points(NumberOfSamples + 1).DataLabel.Width = 200
```

Then I put data labels in an array.

```
 Set sers = Worksheets(sh).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection

'if there are no plots on curve
If sers.Count = 0 Then

    Exit Sub

End If

ReDim dLabels(1 To sers.Count)

For i = 1 To sers.Count
   
    Set dLabels(i) = sers(i).Points(NumberOfSamples + 1).DataLabel
    Debug.Print dLabels(i).Top

Next
```

When I look at the dLabels.Top using a watch, the value is correct. However when the dLabels.Top value is printed out in debug window the value does not match what is in the array. I have the dLabels array set as Datalabel

I then sort the top values going from highest first and start moving them to prevent overlap. Because of this when later I try to move the labels they are incorrect since they have wrong top position

Can anyone help? Not sure if this makes a difference but I do have a multi monitor setup.

Comment: Please, try posting the data labels sorting based on their top values **code**. Do you know that the `Top` property of a chart `DataLabel` means the distance in points *between the label top and the chart top*? I mean, if you want to raise a label position you should use `.Top = .Top - 10`. Did you sort them based on this object peculiarity?

Comment: I wrote an article about this problem a while back: [Prevent Overlapping Data Labels in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/prevent-overlapping-data-labels-in-excel-charts/)